# Python socket to receive information back from the server?

Tags: python, sockets

In Windows I'm currently working on a client/server program.  The client program sends a windows username to the server.  The server program uses the os.system to run a 'net user' command on the username.  This works.

I want to have the server send the results from the Windows 'net user' command back to the client client.
Here are my working programs:

client.py

```
import sys
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

SERVER_IP   = '10.x.xxx.xxx'
PORT_NUMBER = 2000
SIZE = 1024
print ("Test client sending packets to IP {0}, via port {1}\n".format(SERVER_IP, PORT_NUMBER))

myMessage1 = input(' Please enter your login name: ')

mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.sendto(myMessage1.encode('ascii'),(SERVER_IP,PORT_NUMBER))

sys.exit()
```

server.py

```
    import subprocess

    import os
    from socket import socket, gethostbyname, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
    import sys

    PORT_NUMBER = 2000
    SIZE = 1024

    hostName = gethostbyname( '0.0.0.0' )

    mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
    mySocket.bind( (hostName, PORT_NUMBER) )

    print ("Test server listening on port {0}\n".format(PORT_NUMBER))

    # Receive no more than 1024 bytes


    while True:
        (data,addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
        print (data.decode())
        batcmd=('net user ' + data.decode() + ' /domain')
        result = os.system(batcmd)

        sys.exit()
```

Now here is what I am trying to add:

client2.py

```
import os
import sys
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM

SERVER_IP   = '10.x.xxx.xxx'
PORT_NUMBER = 2000
SIZE = 1024
print ("Test client sending packets to IP {0}, via port {1}\n".format(SERVER_IP, PORT_NUMBER))

myMessage1 = input(' Please enter your login name: ')

mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.sendto(myMessage1.encode('ascii'),(SERVER_IP,PORT_NUMBER))


# Receive result from server ?
(data,addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
print (result.decode())

sys.exit()
```

server2.py

```
    import subprocess

    import os
    from socket import socket, gethostbyname, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
    import sys

    PORT_NUMBER = 2000
    SIZE = 1024

    hostName = gethostbyname( '0.0.0.0' )

    mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
    mySocket.bind( (hostName, PORT_NUMBER) )

    print ("Test server listening on port {0}\n".format(PORT_NUMBER))

    # Receive no more than 1024 bytes


    while True:
        (data,addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
        print (data.decode())
        batcmd=('net user ' + data.decode() + ' /domain')
        result = os.system(batcmd)

        # send result back to client ?
        mySocket.send(result.encode('ascii'))
        sys.exit()
```

Any suggestions on how I can do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you're sending information across a connectionless datagram socket (UDP). That's why you server can't reply -- it doesn't have any way to communicate back.

You probably should be using a stream socket (TCP) which creates a connection between the two processes.

Alternatively, you hard-code a datagram socket to listen on in your client & your server magically "knows" which socket and blindly sends the answer to that socket. (Don't do this)... that's why we invented TCP.